# Rspec problem while testing the change of login settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am performing web site integration tests, (Rails,Rspec,Capybara,Selenium - and I'm new to all).  I need to test that a changed email address will be successful successfully persisted.  The problem is that login is based upon email address, so after this change is made, I won't be able to log in again until I have reverted these changes.  What's more, I can't be sure that the test that changes the email address will be successful (actually it currently fails), so I might not even get to the piece of code that changes the email address back.  This means that all later tests fail because login is unsuccessful.

How is this situation usually handled?  Is there any way that I can ensure that code is run after an Rspec test?

Note: I have no access to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the after routine. It's like a teardown in Test::Unit

All code in a after(:each) is executed after each code. the after(:all) is after the describe.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense!  Shows how new I am to Rspec.  Thanks.